# How can I describe this property of divisibility in Idris?

Tags: idris

I want to prove that if b (Integer) divides a (Integer), then b also divides a * c (where c is an Integer). First, I need to reformulate the problem into a computer understandable problem, here was an attempt:

```
-- If a is divisible by b, then there exists an integer such that a = b * n
divisibleBy : (a, b : Integer) ->
              (n : Integer **
              (a = b * n))

-- If b | a then b | ac.
alsoDividesMultiples : (a, b, c : Integer) ->
                       (divisibleBy a b) ->
                       (divisibleBy (a * c) b)
```

However, I am getting `TypeUnification failure`. I am not really sure what is wrong.

```
  |
7 | alsoDividesMultiples : (a, b, c : Integer) ->
  |                      ^
When checking type of Numbris.Divisibility.alsoDividesMultiples:
Type mismatch between
        (n : Integer ** a = b * n) (Type of divisibleBy a b)
and
        Type (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                (n : Integer ** a = prim__mulBigInt b n)
        and
                TypeUnification failure


In context:
        a : Integer
        b : Integer
        c : Integer
        {a_509} : Integer
        {b_510} : Integer
```

Comment: Can you include the full program, or at least your implementations of the variables described here? It's difficult to know what's happening just from this.

Comment: @Kwarrtz There is only one additional line of `module Numbris.Divisibility` (for a later package). However, it can be removed and the same exact error message will be given. In other words, this is the full program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Idris, propositions are represented by types, while proofs of propositions are represented by elements of those types. The basic issue here is that you have defined `divisibleBy` as a function which returns an element (i.e. a proof) rather than a type (proposition). Thus, as you've defined it here, `divisbleBy` actually purports to be a proof that all integers are divisible by all other integers, which is clearly not true! I think what you're actually looking for is something like this.

```
DivisibleBy : Integer -> Integer -> Type
DivisibleBy a b = (n : Integer ** a = b * n)

alsoDividesMultiples : (a, b, c : Integer) ->
                       DivisibleBy a b ->
                       DivisibleBy (a * c) b
```