# How do you operate on dependent pairs in a proof?

Tags: idris

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52799362/667648). Thanks to Kwartz I now have a state of the proposition if b divides a then b divides a * c for any integer c, namely:

```
alsoDividesMultiples : (a, b, c : Integer) ->
                       DivisibleBy a b ->
                       DivisibleBy (a * c) b
```

Now, the goal has been to prove that statement. I realized that I do not understand how to operate on dependent pairs. I tried a simpler problem, which was show that every number is divisible by 1. After a shameful amount of thought on it, *I thought* I had come up with a solution:

```
-- All numbers are divisible by 1.
DivisibleBy a 1 = let n = a in
  (n : Integer ** a = 1 * n)
```

This compiles, but I was had doubts it was valid. To verify that I was wrong, it changed it slightly to:

```
-- All numbers are divisible by 1.
DivisibleBy a 1 = let n = a in
  (n : Integer ** a = 2 * n)
```

This also compiles, which means my "English" interpretation is certainly incorrect, for I would interpret this as "All numbers are divisible by one since every number is two times another integer". Thus, I am not entirely sure what I am demonstrating with that statement. So, I went back and tried a more conventional way of stating the problem:

```
oneDividesAll : (a : Integer) ->
                (DivisibleBy a 1)
oneDividesAll a = ?sorry
```

For the implementation of `oneDividesAll` I am not really sure how to "inject" the fact that `(n = a)`. For example, I would write (in English) this proof as:

> We wish to show that 1 | a. If so, it follows that `a = 1 * n` for some n. Let `n = a`, then `a = a * 1`, which is true by identity.

I am not sure how to really say: "Consider when `n = a`". From my understanding, the `rewrite` tactic requires a proof that `n = a`.

I tried adapting my fallacious proof:

```
oneDividesAll : (a : Integer) ->
                (DivisibleBy a 1)
oneDividesAll a = let n = a in (n : Integer ** a = b * n)
```

But this gives:

```
   |
12 | oneDividesAll a = let n = a in (n : Integer ** a = b * n)
   |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When checking right hand side of oneDividesAll with expected type
        DivisibleBy a 1

Type mismatch between
        Type (Type of DPair a P)
and
        (n : Integer ** a = prim__mulBigInt 1 n) (Expected type)
```

Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you want to prove properties on number, you should use `Nat` (or other inductive types). `Integer` uses primitives that the argument can't argue further than `prim__mulBigInt : Integer -> Integer -> Integer`; that you pass two `Integer` to get one. The compiler doesn't know *anything* how the resulting `Integer` looks like, so it cannot prove stuff about it.

So I'll go along with `Nat`:

```
DivisibleBy : Nat -> Nat -> Type
DivisibleBy a b = (n : Nat ** a = b * n)
```

Again, this is a proposition, not a proof. `DivisibleBy 6 0` is a valid type, but you won't find a `proof : Divisible 6 0`. So you were right with

```
oneDividesAll : (a : Nat) ->
                (DivisibleBy a 1)
oneDividesAll a = ?sorry
```

With that, you could generate proofs of the form `oneDividesAll a : DivisibleBy a 1`. So, what comes into the hole `?sorry`? `:t sorry` gives us `sorry : (n : Nat ** a = plus n 0)` (which is just `DivisibleBy a 1` resolved as far as Idris can). You got confused on the right part of the pair: `x = y` is a type, but now we need a value – that's what's your last error cryptic error message hints at). `=` has only one constructor, `Refl : x = x`. So we need to get both sides of the equality to the same value, so the result looks something like `(n ** Refl)`.

As you thought, we need to set `n` to `a`:

```
oneDividesAll a = (a ** ?hole)
```

For the needed rewrite tactic we check out `:search plus a 0 = a`, and see `plusZeroRightNeutral` has the right type.

```
oneDividesAll a = (a ** rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral a in ?hole)
```

Now `:t hole` gives us `hole : a = a` so we can just auto-complete to `Refl`:

```
oneDividesAll a = (a ** rewrite plusZeroRightNeutral a in Refl)
```

A good tutorial on theorem proving (where it's also explained why `plus a Z` does not reduce) is in the [Idris Doc](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/theorems.html).

Comment: Thanks! One question: Technically the `Integer` type contains negative numbers and `Nat` does not. Is there an `Integer` inductive type, or does that need to be constructed?

Comment: There is already [Data.ZZ](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Data/ZZ.idr) in the contrib package. You need to run Idris with `idris file.idr -p contrib` to include it.